Mapping between Google Place API business type and Google MyBusiness Profile business category
Is there a way to find the mapping between the Place API business type and the business category as shown on the MyBusiness Profile?
Trying to filter on a certain business type (restaurants) using the Google Place API but I'm then missing the business category Event Venue and Pub. The business categories are not defined as business type
